# Using Machine Learning in Python to load custom datasets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

**Here's the problem:** 
It take 2 variable inputs, and predict a result.

**For example**: `price` and `volume` as inputs and a decision to buy/sell as a `result`.

I tried implementing this using `K-Neighbors` with no success. How would you go about this?

```
X = cleanedData['ES1 End Price'] #only accounts for 1 variable, don't know how to use input another. 
y = cleanedData["Result"]
print(X.shape, y.shape)
kmm = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
kmm.fit(X,y) #ValueError for size inconsistency, but both are same size.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the definition of `cleanedData`

Comment: Is the problem the custom data, or how to get a prediction form a classifier?

Comment: this are same raw count ? what's error ?

Comment: Hi all, I'm declaring the cleanedData from an excel file. I'm wondering how I would essentially use two variables are inputs: i.e., how to declare those.

Comment: What is the type of `cleanedData`? Is it a dataframe? If so, then you can pass a list of column names in it to access them.

Comment: @VivekKumar, yes. It is a DataFrame, and I got the inputs down. The fit is giving me some trouble. 

kmm.fit(X[:,None],y)  # TypeError: unhashable type

Comment: What's the shape of X?

Comment: @VivekKumar, (2617, 2) for X and 2617L for y.

Comment: Then just pass X, dont use X[:None].

Comment: @VivekKumar, thanks for your help! Mind guiding me through how to predict? Let's say a price of $2,400 and a volume of 2,000, predict buy (0) or sell (1). How would I write this as a predict()? Thanks in advance.

Comment: knn.predict([[2400, 2000]]).

Answer (score 2):

`X` needs to be a [matrix/2d array](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) where each column stands for a feature, which doesn't seem true from your code, try reshape `X` to 2d with `X[:,None]`:

```
kmm.fit(X[:,None], y)
```

---

Or without resorting to reshape, you'd better always use a list to extract features from a data frame:

```
X = cleanedData[['ES1 End Price']]
```

OR with more than one columns:

```
X = cleanedData[['ES1 End Price', 'volume']]
```

Then X would be a 2d array, and can be used directly in `fit`:

```
kmm.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: This helped with the error, but I'm wondering how I would declare X to how two columns. So far, all I have is X = cleanedData['ES1 End Price'], but I need to include volume as well. Any thoughts? Would the suggestion above still hold given another dimension?

Comment: if you have a dataframe, you can do `cleanedData[['ES1 End Price', 'volume']]` and no need to reshape this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - just implemented that above, but now I'm getting a TypeError: unhashable type, on the kmm.fit(X[:,None], y) line. Suggestions?